# JQUERY como somar tag <p>

Tags: jquery, html

Sou novo no JQuery  e gostaria de saber como eu somo duas tags `<p>` sem input, por exemplo:

```
<p>Valor do Pedido: <span  id="resultado" class="resultado">5</span></p>
<p>Taxa de Entrega: <span id="txa"  class="txa">5</span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="tot" class="tot"></span></p>
```

Gostaria de somar esses dois valores : *valor + taxa = total*, só que o JQuery só reconhece quando eu uso input, e isso  não era bem o que eu queria usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var valor = $("#valor").text();
  var taxa = $("#txa").text();
  var total = Number(valor) + Number(taxa);
  $("#tot").text(total);
});
```

```html
<p>Valor do Pedido: <span  id="valor" class="valor">5</span></p>
<p>Taxa de Entrega: <span id="txa"  class="txa">5</span></p>
<p>Total: <span id="tot" class="tot"></span></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```